# uefi specifications example mentions EfiCoreImageHandle. How to get it?

Tags: c, specifications, boot, bootloader, uefi

Quoting the UEFI specifications section about EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.HandleProtocol():

> The HandleProtocol() function is still available for use by old EFI
>   applications and drivers. However, all new applications and drivers
>   should use EFI_BOOT_SERVICES.OpenProtocol() in place of
>   HandleProtocol(). The following code fragment shows a possible
>   implementation of HandleProtocol() using OpenProtocol(). The variable
>   EfiCoreImageHandle is the image handle of the EFI core.

```
EFI_STATUS
HandleProtocol (
     IN EFI_HANDLE   Handle,
     IN EFI_GUID     *Protocol,
     OUT VOID        **Interface
     )
    {
     return OpenProtocol (
           Handle,
           Protocol,
           Interface,
           EfiCoreImageHandle,
           NULL,
           EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_BY_HANDLE_PROTOCOL
           );
    }
```

End of quote.

My question is: how to get the value for EfiCoreImageHandle when an EFI application was run by a boot manager, or from a UEFI shell?

Comment: I don’t think there is a way for an application to get it; at least not a standard way. There may be a way for a debugger to get it. I don’t think there is typically any need for an application to use it. When calling OpenProtocol, you should pass your own image handle.

Comment: @prl, (1) Does that mean you think the specifications ought to get fixed? I was quoting the specification. I think they should be authoritative. (2) Do you suggest to have the same variable passed both to the 4th and 1st parameter? That is, in the case of the example, set both the 1st, and the 4th, parameters to Handle? `return OpenProtocol(Handle, Protocol, Interface, Handle, NULL,           EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_BY_HANDLE_PROTOCOL);`

Comment: No, I don't think the spec needs to be fixed. I think you are misunderstanding it. It says that new applications shouldn't call HandleProtocol. You should call OpenProtocol with your own image handle. But if an old application calls HandleProtocol, it behaves as if OpenProtocol were called with the arguments shown.

Comment: The first parameter is the handle on which you want to open a protocol. The fourth parameter is the image handle. They would be the same only if you are opening a protocol on the image handle (for example LoadedImageProtocol).

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, `EfiCoreImageHandle` is just a placeholder in the specification. Have a look at how I invoke `OpenProtocol` in the `ShowEDID` utility in https://github.com/fpmurphy/UEFI-Utilities-2019.

Also look at the `ShowUSB` utility where I currently use `HandleProtocol`, i.e.

```
Status = gBS->HandleProtocol( HandleBuffer[Index],
                              &gEfiUsbIoProtocolGuid,
                              (VOID**)&UsbIo );
```

I could replace the above code with:

```
Status = gBS->OpenProtocol( HandleBuffer[Index],
                            &gEfiUsbIoProtocolGuid,
                            (VOID **)&UsbIo,
                            gImageHandle,
                            NULL,
                            EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_BY_HANDLE_PROTOCOL );
```

Tested with UDK2018 and Lenovo T480